# I get an identifier expected error. Why?

Tags: java

Why am I getting identifier expected errors here? It is a separate class from the main class, used to describe the rooms I have to move throughout. But, I do not know why I am getting this error.

```
public class DescribeRoom{
    protected int roomNum;
    public DescribeRoom(roomNum){
        this.roomNum = roomNum;
    }//end constructor
    public String describe(roomNum){
        String[] room = {"You find yourself in a nicely trimmed front yard. There is a front door to your north.",
            "You walk into the southern part of the main hall. You can't help but be amazed by the decor.You see the front door to the south, and rooms to the east and west. There is more of the hall to the north.",
            "You are in the northern part of the main hall. To the south is the rest of the hall, and there are doors to the north, west and east.",
            "You walk into the bathroom. It smells of lemon. There are doors to the south and east.",
            "You walk into a tidy bedroom. There are doors to the south and east.",
            "You walk into the living room. It has couches and a fairly sized television. There are doors to the west and south.",
            "You walk into the dining room. It has a large table in the middle with some candles. There are doors to the west, north, and east.",
            "You walk into a large kitchen. Seems to be large enough to house a full staff. There is a door to the west and north.",
            "You walk out onto a wooden deck that overlooks the back yard. there is only the door to the south from which you came.",
            "You walk out of the house and into the back yard. It is surrounded by a fence too large to climb. There is only the door to the south from which you came."};
        return room[roomNum];
    }
}//end class
```

Comment: Java functions look like this: `Type functionName(Type identifier, ...)`

Answer (score 1):

in the method parameter you have not set any identifier.

use like `describe(int roomNum)`

Answer (score 0):

Every method in Java has a return type and you need to specify the datatype while passing the parameters.

`public DescribeRoom(roomNum)`
should be `public void DescribeRoom(int roomNum)`

1. `DescribeRoom` method won't return anything.
2. Method understands that the `roomNum` is of type int.

Similarly, `public String describe(int roomNum)`

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor signature is missing its' type. This,

```
public DescribeRoom(roomNum){
```

should be

```
public DescribeRoom(int roomNum){
```

and

```
public String describe(roomNum){
```

should be

```
public String describe(int roomNum){
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem(that I conclude) is a syntax error because you didn't declare the type of the parameter roomNum to be integer in both the constructor and describe method. After fixing this, your code should work fine. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm

Try that tutorial bro when you are creating a method.